# Which Power is preferred in Yamaha PSR-E423 (AC Adapter or Battery)

Tags: music

I am using an Yamaha PSR-E423 Keyboard.

This is the [User Manual](http://file:///C:/Users/hp/Downloads/_home_httpd_data_media-data_f_psre423_en_om_c0-.pdf)

From the manual, I understand that we can power the keyboard through the AC Adapter or through 6 number of 1.5V batteries. (9V in total)

Suppose, If I connect both the AC Adapter and provide the battery power to the keyboard, which power will the keyoard use for its functions?

And in the event of power interruptions, will the keyboard continue if its battery powered?

Comment: HW Recs is focused on giving pre-purchase recommendations for primary computing hardware rather than technical support or **details**. As you are not directly seeking an item to interface with a primary computing platform I am flagging to close this question. You may find your question is a better fit for one of our sister sites like [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Ok. But if I delete my question, what happens to my reputation?

Comment: ["Questions with a bounty cannot be closed, or deleted"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115281/what-happens-if-i-delete-a-question-with-a-bounty). I believe that if the moderator deems my flag valid, [they have the option to refund the reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14591/how-can-we-close-questions-with-bounties/27103#27103).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't asking for a computer hardware recommendation.

Comment: @Newbie I was also able to refund your rep that you spent on the bounty, so no worries there.